# taking a character input in python from a file?

Tags: python, file

in python , suppose i have file data.txt . which has 6 lines of data . I want to calculate the no of lines which i am planning to do by going through each character and finding out the number of '\n' in the file . How to take one character input from the file ? Readline takes the whole line .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the method you're looking for is `readlines`, as in

```
lines = open("inputfilex.txt", "r").readlines()
```

This will give you a list of each of the lines in the file. To find out how many lines, you can just do:

```
len(lines)
```

And then access it using indexes, like `lines[3]` or `lines[-1]` as you would any normal Python list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read(1)` to read a single byte. `help(file)` says:

> `read(`*size*`)` -> read at most *size* bytes, returned as a string.
>
> If the *size* argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
>        Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
>        may be returned, even if no *size* parameter was given.

Note that reading a file a byte at a time is quite un-"Pythonic". This is par for the course in C, but Python can do a lot more work with far less code. For example, you can read the entire file into an array in one line of code:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

You could then access by line number with a simple `lines[lineNumber]` lookup.

Or if you don't want to store the entire file in memory at once, you can iterate over it line-by-line:

```
for line in f:
    # Do whatever you want.
```

That is much more readable and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simplest answer for you would be to do:

```
for line in file:
    lines += 1
    # do whatever else you need to do for each line
```

Or the equivalent construction explicitly using `readline()`.  I'm not sure why you want to look at every character when you said above that `readline()` is correctly reading each line in its entirety.

Comment: suppose i want to iterate to ith line in the file . How will I do that using readline? .. are you saying me to put a loop and do readline() that many no of times?

Answer (score 0):

To access a file based on its lines, make a list of its lines.

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

then simply access `lines[3]` to get the fourth line and so forth. (Note that this will not strip the newline characters.)

The [linecache module](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html) can also be useful for this.